# To post multiple groups to service now and fetch all the tickets related to those groups

Tags: servicenow

I need to post multiple groups to service now and get all the tickets corresponding to all those groups.

Is there any Service Noe API or Web Service available to do this.
Please help me to do so.

Comment: What have you tried? There is a REST interface https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc

Comment: Thanks you, Let me check this link, and will update the result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a REST API which you could've found by spending literally three seconds on Google.

https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=jakarta&id=c_TableAPI
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound_rest/concept/c_RESTAPI.html

As those articles state, you can literally get the exact code you need to perform these requests by opening the **Rest API Explorer** module in your instance.

Comment: Thank you, I need to pass a set of SNOW groups have to passed to get INC number,state, Assignee, Assigned group, title, created by. The format in which the set of assignment groups has to be passed

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not understand you. If you had another question, please rephrase.